# How do I change the color of the header row in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, ide, editor

Attached is a picture for reference. There is a spot in the header bar that shows the current class and method. How does one change the background color of it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Breadcrumbs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/navigating-with-breadcrumbs.html) were introduced for java in v2016.2 and as you can see on their [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/06/intellij-idea-2016-2-eap-adds-breadcrumb-for-java/#comment-379393), currently it's not possible to change their color:

> Andrey Cheptsov says:
>
> July 21, 2016 at 11:52 am
>
> Currently it’s not possible but were working to fix that.

A quick search on the tracker revealed (amongst others) [IDEA-162359 The breadcrumb colour cannot be changed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162359) which you can probably watch to get notified when things change.